# Android Studio on Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit not working

Tags: 12.04, android, 32-bit, android-studio

I installed Android Studio on my 32 bit ubuntu 12.04. But when I try to start it, I get the message:

Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool. One common reason for this failure is missing required libraries
I found a lot of solutions, but all of them are for people who use a 64 bit ubuntu system and need to install some 32 bit libraries.

Do you have any idea, why the mksdcard SDK tool isn't working on my 32 bit system?

Thanks, Tim

Comment: Try running this command, this should work with 32 bit systems: `sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6`

Comment: This is what I've already found and tried, but it tells me that "the packages have no installation candidates".